# I have an array with two fields value and I want to echo separatly

Tags: php

I have and id and name field in a array variable how can I echo them separately in the fallowing html.

```
foreach($iterator as $key=>$value)
```

The variable $value has id and name field I want to echo them in separately like

```
<div>id here</div>   <div>name here</div>
```

I have tried this

```
    $hier = new hier;
    $iterator = $hier->Pathroot($name);
    try {

        foreach($iterator as $key=>$value)
            {

    echo '<div>' . $value['id'] . '</div><div>' . $value['name'] . '</div>'

    }
```

I took the recursiveiterator function because I am not using my old sql model any more therefore I am don't have to use recursiveiterator anymore.

Var_dump

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(14) "Coloso" ["id"]=> string(1) "1" } }
```

Comment: So what have you tried already?

Comment: Further to @Oli's comment, could you define the `$iterator` array? Is it an array of arrays, or an array with values of a specific format?

Comment: *The variable $value has id and name field* Does this mean you have a multidimensional array? I guess you should definitely read http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: @OLi I have tried what is above and it only print the first character of the name field, and the id but the id is coming I guess is being iterated from the last div. meaning that only the name field is echoing the name and the id value.....i get <div>'.$value['id'].'</div> it will still return the first character of the name field and the id as well.

Comment: @thomas and @felix it is a multidimensional array I should probably refer it to  $iterator[0]['id']
I think it is a multidimensional array like array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(14) "Coloso" ["id"]=> string(1) "1" } }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iterator contains an array of arrays like so:

```
array(
  // counter => array(id, name)
  0 => array("1", "john"),
  1 => array("2", "jane")
  etc...
)
```

On each foreach loop the iterator internally increases its counter so that the next sub-array is returned, e.g.:

```
foreach ($iterator as $index => $value) {
    // loop 1: index=0; value=array(id=1, name=john)
    // loop 2: index=1; value=array(id=2, name=jane)
    // loop 3: index=2; counter > count(array) - break
}
```

So if you use `$value` you should get the result you need.

Comment: I think it is a multidimensional array like array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(14) "Coloso" ["id"]=> string(1) "1" } }

Comment: I haven't used these SPL classes (if you can make sense of http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/ that might help you) - but do you need to wrap RecursiveArrayIterator in RecursiveIteratorIterator? It looks like you can get what you want from the ArrayIterator.

Comment: Also if you do this you can use $key and $value as Dagon suggested. What does a var_dump of the current $key and $value give?

Comment: Can you explain that var dump   array like array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(14) "Coloso" ["id"]=> string(1) "1" } }

Comment: That's a var dump without the recursive iterator function I took it out

Comment: Is that a var_dump of $iterator? If so just use $key and $value - what I think's happening is that on each foreach loop it sets $key and $value to $(internal)[loop_count]["key"] and $(...)[loop_count]["value"]. I'll update my answer to show this.

Comment: yes that's the var_dump for $iterator,So what would be the loop_count place value in there according to the var_dump, I have try $iterator[0]['name']; because according to the var_dump there are two array so as you saying there should be a place for loop_count.

Comment: That should work, what do you get when you var_dump($iterator->current()) in the loop?

Comment: wait ross I am going to var_dump to see the results of this as well

Comment: Ross when I var_dumped it var_dump($iterator->current()) there was an error like this  Fatal error: Call to a member function current() on a non-object in /home3/nyhungry/public_html/parent2/children.php on line 121

Comment: @fello: Have a look (and run) this sample: https://gist.github.com/951025, does this help? $value should contain the array you want - so you'll use $value["name"] to get the name. Sorry for taking you the long way around, I should sit down and try things before posting them :-)

Comment: yes that one echo the user field, so this way worked even with the RecursiveArrayIterator function.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried the obvious:

```
echo "<div>$key</div><div>$value</div>";
```

Comment: Dragon within the value is where the two values I want to echo are.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div><?php echo $value['id'] ?></div>    <div><?php echo $value['name'] ?></div>
```

Comment: it is a multimentional array I guess this is the var_dump 
I think it is a multidimensional array like array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(14) "Coloso" ["id"]=> string(1) "1" } }

Comment: @fello: Of course, but `$value` is already the iteration variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need find out whether you're dealing with an associative array, or a non-associative array.

An associative array maps keys to values. In your code, if `$value` is an associative array:

`echo '<div>' . $value['id'] . '</div><div>' . $value['name'] . '</div>';`

Would work! (you're missing the ending semicolon in your code by the way, but I'm guessing thats just a paste error).

If not, `$value` is simply a non-associative array, so you need to create another loop, to print the values:

```
foreach($iterator as $key=>$value){
    foreach($value as $val){
        echo '<div>'.$val.'</div>';
    }
}
```

Your syntax suggests that you're **are** dealing with an associative array, but again; your code would work.

*As a sidenote, the following two lines of code are equivalent (assuming $value is an associative array again):*

```
foreach($iterator as $key=>$value) echo $value['name'];
foreach($iterator as $value) echo $value['name'];
```

Comment: foreach($iterator as $value) echo $value['name'];
this line made it, it printed the value of both.. now does this mean it is a associated array? I took the value of $key and left only the $value and now it worked. Thanks

Comment: If it printed both values correctly, $value is an associative array, but the 'id' value seems to be located in the 'name' key. Anyway, glad it worked.